# getting "UNDEFINED" in alert box in browser when runing a web program

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="contactinfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication17.contactinfo1" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnsave').click(function () {
                    var ContactName = $('#<%=txtcontactname.ClientID%>').val();
                    var ContactNo = $('#<%=txtcontactno.ClientID%>').val();
                    $('#savedata').show();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "contactinfo.aspx/SaveData",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            "ContactName": ContactName,
                            "COntactNo": ContactNo
                        }),
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d == "success") {
                                alert("data saved successfully");
                                var ContactName = $('#<%=txtcontactname.ClientID%>').val('');
                                var ContactNo = $('#<%=txtcontactno.ClientID%>').val('');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                    }).done(function () {
                        $('#savedata').hide();
                    });


                });
            });
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td>contact Name: </td>
          <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtcontactname" runat="server" Width="200px" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>contact No: </td>
          <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtcontactno" runat="server" Width="200px" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="button" id="btnsave" value="submit results" /></td>
          <td><div ID="savedata" style=" color:Green; font-family:Comic Sans MS; font-weight:bold; display:none;">data saving...</div></td>
        </tr>

     </table>
    </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Check your response data in Firebug.

Comment: Its coming from javascript. Check it.